# Android Data Binding don't work correctly on Recycle View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I have `RecycleView` that contains list of messages I want to use android data binding to fill text and time of every row of my *Recycleview* but I have strange problem that after binding message to every row, `TextView` of text and time fill with empty text like you don't set any text!

my RecyceView Adapter:

```
 @Override
public BaseRVHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    viewGroup=parent;
    View view= layoutInflater.inflate(layout[viewType], null);
    try {
        return holder.getConstructor(View.class,LayoutInflater.class,ViewGroup.class,Context.class).newInstance(view,layoutInflater,viewGroup,context);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public Object getItem(int position){
    if(position<items.size())
        return items.get(position);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseRVHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder!=null)
        holder.fill(context,layoutInflater,viewGroup,items.get(position),position,getItemViewType(position),getObjects());

}
 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if(messages.get(position).getFrom() == homeId){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

and fill() method of my ViewHolder of message:

```
@Override
    public void fill(final Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, final Message message, int pos, int viewType, Object... objects) {
        if(viewType==0) {
            AdapterMessageSendActivitytBinding binding = AdapterMessageSendActivitytBinding.inflate(this.inflater);
            binding.setMessage(message);
            binding.notifyChange();
            binding.invalidateAll();
        }else {
            AdapterMessageReceiveActivityBinding binding =AdapterMessageReceiveActivityBinding.inflate(this.inflater);
            binding.setMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Message.java:

```
public class Message extends BaseModel implements Serializable{

@PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
private int id;
@Column
private int from;
@Column
private String username;
@Column
private String text;
@Column
transient DateTime dateTime;

private List<ToMessage> recipients;

//getter and setters are here...
```

and layout of adapter:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="message"
            type="com.example.familydesk.model.Message"></variable>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="56dp" android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:src="@drawable/house_logo"/>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_back_white_nine_patch"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/contentTv"
                android:text="@{message.text}"
                android:gravity="right"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{message.dateTime.toString()}"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/time_dateTv"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

whats wrong with my code??can anybody help plz?

Comment: I think your implementation of recyclerview is too complex. refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create binding object in constructor of `ViewHolder` like below :

```
public BaseRVHolder(View view){
    binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
}
```

and don't forget to call `executePendingBindings()` after setting value.

```
binding.setMessage(message);
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

refer [this](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part2/) tutorial for more information.